# Why does my sub-NgModule not see a custom pipe defined in the root NgModule?

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I am working on a large project that has a shared module for reusable components. This module has a lot of components, and I'm attempting to group some of the related components into submodules for functionality reuse and organization.

My issue is that upon creating a submodule, I'm getting some errors in some of the submodule components. For example, one component uses a custom pipe that also lives in `/shared/`. Now that the component is scoped to it's submodule, it's not seeing that this custom pipe is available, where as before it was no issue.

Here is a rough example of what I'm talking about.. this doesn't include `/shared/`, but for simplicity's sake, assume `app.module` is the "shared" module.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fxvp6

Answer (score 2):

To use a pipe in two different `NgModule`, you have to create a [shared module](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules).

> You can put commonly used directives, pipes, and components into one module and then import just that module wherever you need it in other parts of your app.

```
@NgModule({
 imports:      [ CommonModule ],
 declarations: [ CapitalizePipe ],
 exports:      [ CapitalizePipe ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

---

To elaborate on our discussion. Once you import two separate shared modules into another module (say AppModule), it does -not- mean that anything you declared in one of those sub modules, is available in the other module. You need to strictly import into a module what you want.

<sub>Great paint work</sub>

[image]

If those two submodules both need something from the `declarations` array, you should create another module, have it declared in that other module, add it to the export of that other module, and import that module in both submodule #1 and submodule #2:

[image]

With this in place you can assume the following (all from the `@NgModule` declarations):

1. Everything that is in the `exports` array of submodule #3 will be available to use in templates of submodule #1, submodule #2 and Appmodule. You can add whatever you have in the declarations of submodule #3 to the exports array, but best practice is to put there just what you want available for the outside world.

   You can also add other `NgModules` in the exports array, without the necessity of adding them to the imports array, if you do not require them in that specific module, but do want it to be available in other modules who import said module.
2. Everything in the exports array of submodule #1 will -only- be available to be used in templates declared in the `AppModule` (again, as well in the submodule #1).
3. Everything in the exports array of submodule #2 will -only- be available to be used in templates declared in the `AppModule` (again, as well in the submodule #2).
4. AppModule should not have anything in its export array.. but it can use all the things exported from the other modules, and components/directives/pipes declared by itself

Comment: My issue is with importing another module into my shared module, e.g. I want a module to contain all modal functionality, and I want this module to be a part of my shared module. When I do this, any time I attempt to use the pipe that is declared in the shared module it's fine, unless I attempt to use the pipe inside of the previously mentioned modal module. Please see my updated stackblitz... I've tried to better illustrate this.

Comment: @Esten again the structure you have there is not correct (hence the error) :) `SubModule` should be imported into the `AppModule`, and `SubModule` should import the `SharedModule`. Also the `BrowserModule` should only be imported by one module, the `AppModule`. The rest should use the `CommonModule`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exuktp

This structure doesn't make sense to me. I'd need to import dozens of modules (modals, forms, buttons) to the root? What then is the point of a shared module? These blocks are meant to be shared.. can a shared module not import other modules if the components within them need access to other imported modules?

Comment: @Esten I've updated my answer with a bit more explanation

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have shared on stackblitz should work. Anything inside app.module is available across the app. There is no need to export pipe from the app.module. but if you do plan to move the pipe to shared module then follow the approach suggested by PierreDuc. So if you have a shared component and shared pipe they would ideally rest in the same module..  call it shared module. Hope this helps.